# How to Access files with www-data Ownership from a PHP Script?

Tags: php

```
$image_path ="images/";
$dir_perms = 0777; //0755;
$file_perms = 0644;

 //sets PHP's umask to mask & 0777 and returns the old umask
 $old_umask= umask(0);
 echo " old umask ==  $old_umask";

 if (mkdir($image_path, 0777, TRUE) )
         echo "created $image_path";
 else
 {
         echo " $image_path failed creation";
         exit();
 }
 /*
 //if (chmod($image_path, 0777) )
 if( chmod( $image_path, $dir_perms))
         echo " $image_path folder set as $dir_perms";
 else
        echo "$image_path failed to chmod to $dir_perms";

  */


//chmod( $create_path,0777);

 $owner = "root";

  // Set the user
if ( chown($image_path, $owner) )
 {
        echo "user changed to root ";

 }
 else
 {
         echo "\n -------- NOT changed to root! ";
         exit();
 }
```

My chown fails. According to some people this is a bad approach because it would let my script change ownership of a file in the "client"'s system.

My main concern is that I want my php script to access the directory it created!
I am probably making some silly mistake. So, when I try to access www-data permission folder, it fails.
If I try to show a image from a directory with root permission, a code I have work.

Comment: Your folder is automatically created with whatever user is executing the PHP script. This is probably apache or www-data. You don't need to do any extra chown or chmod

Comment: So, you are saying that I should be able to access files in a www-data folder?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special to the permissions if you only plan on opening the folder's contents with PHP

Comment: Yes, kinghfb and Jake. I agree that the approach is horrible. I want to only access the files in www-data, but I am unable to do it. Even, if I change file permissions to 777. On the other hand, if I try to access files from a public directory created from the linux shell the php code would show the image. Let me update my code to show the image call.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I found the error, it was on move
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
I didn't know that the second parameter(destination) required also a name. So, I just passed directory and it failed. Thank you all. : )